# создание django commands

Tags: python, django

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня есть файл с вопросами и вариантами ответов. Есть модели вопрос и ответ в джанго. Мне нужно эти данные (csv файл) закинуть вопросы в модель вопроса, ответы в модель ответа. Читаю про django command. Мне чтение файла и его обработку в методе handle делать или отдельно? Идея я так понял в том, чтобы эти данный в цикле записывать в модель (создавать экземпляр класса), верно?

написал отдель csv_reader(), возвращает список из кортежей (первый элемент вопрос, второй словарь из вариантов)
Разместил файл в одной папке с файлом командой, пишет, что No such file or directory: 'qs.csv'
Что делаю не так?

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Displays current time'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        questions = csv_reader('qs.csv')
        for q in questions:
            Question.objects.create(question_text=q[0])
        for option in questions:
            Choice.objects.create(choice_text=option[1].keys())
```

а еще если сам файл с классом команды пытаюсь запустить, пишет django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: «Что делаю не так» — запускаете команду не из той папки, в которой лежит qs.csv

Comment: я тоже так подумал, поместил все в одну папку и ничего, все так же

Comment: Нужно поместить не в какую-то там «одну папку», а в текущую рабочую папку.

Comment: я сделал как по документации: в папке проекта management, затем commands, там содал файл, где написал csv_reader и класс для комманды, в эту же папку поместил файл csv

Comment: А надо помещать не в эту же папку, а в текущую рабочую папку. Все относительные пути всегда высчитываются относительно текущей рабочей папки — и это касается вообще любых программ, не только python/django.

Comment: в папку приложения или проекта?

Comment: В текущую рабочую папку. Какая папка является текущей в тот момент, когда вы запускаете команду — знаете только вы. Текущей папкой может быть абсолютно любая папка на вашем компьютере.

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое команды джанго? они размещаются только в одном месте.  В любом случае, перемещение ни в папку с приложением, ни в папку проекта не решило проблемы.

Comment: Я работаю с Django уже почти шесть лет и прекрасно знаю, что такое команды джанго. Да, команды джанго действительно размещаются только в одном месте. Но это не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к текущей рабочей папке — вы можете запускать команды джанго находясь в ЛЮБОЙ папке вашего компьютера. И из какой папки запускаете команду вы — мы никак не можем знать.

Comment: как мне написали ниже, я поместил файл туда, откуда запускаю manage.py, но ошибка все та же, к сожалению.

Comment: Проверяйте `os.getcwd()` и `os.listdir('.')`

Comment: Напишите, как именно вы запускаете команду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда открываете файл на чтение методом `open` и при этом указываете не полный путь, то файл открывается относительно `текущей рабочей директории` (current working folder), у каждого процесса такая есть. Посмотреть можно `import os; print(os.getcwd())`.

Когда запускаете джанго команду выполняя `manage.py <command>`, то текущая рабочая директория будет та, из которой вы выполняете `manage.py` и соответственно `qs.csv` должен находится в той директории, если ваша функция `csv_reader` просто делает `open('qs.csv')`, т.е. не добавляет ничего у пути и не меняет сама текущую директорию.

> если сам файл с классом команды пытаюсь запустить, пишет django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Это ожидаемо. Основное, что делает `manage.py`, это устанавливает переменную `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` чтобы джанго могла инициализироваться.

Comment: спасибо, понял, но ошибка все равно есть

Comment: перед `open` вставьте код проверки текущей директории из ответа

Comment: важно как вы запускаете команду. Если из консоли, то текущая директория будет как написано, а если, скажем, из IDE, то там может быть настроена другая текущая директория, которая будет использована для запуска.

Comment: спасибо. из IDE, нахожусь в /home/user/PProjects/djangoProject, сюда же поместил файл